Emulating C23's QChar * behavior for basename and strchrnul
To quote @Lundin from What is C23 and why should I care?:

Bug fixes for a lot of library functions (search functions in particular): we can now pass a const-qualified pointer parameter to a library function and assign the result of the function to a similarly const-qualified pointer. These new features are named QChar and QVoid and are only used for char* and void* parameters to certain library functions.
A lot of library functions in C have been broken by design since the dawn of time - for example it was not possible to write a string parser using strstr like: current = strstr(current, key) in case current was properly const correct as const char*... because strstr returns a char*. A lot of C library functions had this "broken by design" API which has now been corrected.
So now these functions look like QChar *strstr(QChar *s1, const char *s2); where QChar or QVoid is a fix which means that the function will return the same type as was passed to s1.

I've used C11's _Generic for this. Both util_basename() and util_strchrnul() have two versions:

vanilla - takes a const char * and returns a char *.
const - takes a const char * and returns a const char *.

Code:
util.h:
#ifndef UTIL_H
#define UTIL_H 1

[[gnu::returns_nonnull]] char *util_basename_vanilla(char path[static 1]);

[[gnu::returns_nonnull]] const char *util_basename_const(const char path[static 1]);

#define util_basename(s)                         \
    _Generic((s),                                \
            char *:       util_basename_vanilla, \
            const char *: util_basename_const)(s)

[[gnu::pure, gnu::returns_nonnull]] char *util_strchrnul_vanilla(
        const char s[static 1], 
        int c);

[[gnu::pure, gnu::returns_nonnull]] const char *util_strchrnul_const(
        const char s[static 1], 
        int c);

#define util_strchrnul(s, c)                      \
    _Generic((s),                                 \
            char *:       util_strchrnul_vanilla, \
            const char *: util_strchrnul_const)(s, c)

#endif                          /* UTIL_H */

util.c:
#include <string.h>

#include "util.h"

#define gen_basename(version, ret_type) \
    ret_type util_basename_##version(const char path[static 1]) { \
        char *const cp = strrchr(path, '/'); \
        return cp ? cp + 1 : path; \
    } 

gen_basename(vanilla, char *)
gen_basename(const, const char *)

#define gen_strchrnul(version, ret_type) \
    ret_type util_strchrnul_##version(const char s[static 1], int c) { \
        while (*s && *s != c) { ++s; } \
        return s; \
    }

gen_strchrnul(vanilla, char *)
gen_strchrnul(const, const char *)

Yes, you can not directly pass a void * (as far as I can recall) to the string functions now. You have to explicitly cast it. It works much like C++ does. This is a feature, not a bug.
Unit Tests:
void test_util_basename(void) 
{
    test(strcmp(util_basename("/usr/lib"), "lib") == 0);
    test(strcmp(util_basename("/usr/"), "") == 0);
    test(strcmp(util_basename("usr"), "usr") == 0);
    test(strcmp(util_basename("/"), "") == 0);
    test(strcmp(util_basename("."), ".") == 0);
    test(strcmp(util_basename(".."), "..") == 0);
}

void test_util_strhcrnul(void)
{
    static const char haystack[] = "hello there";
    test(util_strchrnul(haystack, 'o') == strchr(haystack, 'o'));
    test(*util_strchrnul(haystack, 'p') == '\0');

#if defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__) || defined(__INTEL_LLVM_COMPILER)
    /* Specify the prototype, because defining _GNU_SOURCE doesn't seem to. */
    char *strchrnul(const char *p, int ch);

    static const char s[] = "hair"; 
    static const char t[] = "gown"; 
    test(util_strchrnul(s, 'h') == strchrnul(s, 'h'));
    test(util_strchrnul(t, 'g') == strchrnul(t, 'g'));
#endif 
}

test() is just an assert().
Review Request:
Anything, everything.
